# What's up with the [OptionalField] Attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, fault-tolerance

As I understand it I have to adorn a new member in a newer version of my class with the [OptionalField] Attribute when I deserialize an older version of my class that lacks this newer member.

However, the code below throws no exception while the InnerTranslator property was added after serializing the class. I check for the property to be null in the onDeserialization method (which confirms that it was not serialized),but I would have expected the code to throw an exception because of that.
Is the [OptionalField] Attribute itself optional?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listcol = new SortedList<string,string>
        {
            {"Estados Unidos", "United States"},
            {"Canadá", "Canada"},
            {"España", "Spain"}
        };
        var translator = new CountryTranslator(listcol);
        using (var file_stream=new FileStream("translator.bin",FileMode.Open))
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            translator = formatter.Deserialize(file_stream) as CountryTranslator;
            file_stream.Close();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[Serializable]
internal class CountryTranslator:IDeserializationCallback
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public CountryTranslator(SortedList<string,string> sorted_list)
    {
        this.country_list = sorted_list;
        inner_translator = new List<string> {"one", "two"};
    }
    //[OptionalField]
    private List<string> inner_translator;
    public List<string> InnerTranslator
    {
        get { return inner_translator; }
        set { inner_translator = value; }
    }

    private SortedList<string, string> country_list;

    public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        Debug.Assert(inner_translator == null);
        Count=country_list.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found out that the SOAP formatter does throw an exception when the inner_translator is not adorned with the [OptionalField] Attribute

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BinaryFormatter` is, at the *best* of times, very brittle if you change things. Not least, there are huge problems with [automatically implemented properties, obfuscaction](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html), renaming, strong naming, etc.

As I recall, some of the rules about `[OptionalField]` changed just before it was released; the version tolerant thing didn't really work out as easily as had been planned, I expect.

My advice: if you want version tolerant serialization (i.e. you can serialize it today and deserialize it with the next version of your app), then don't use `BinaryFormatter`; this is (IMO) only suitable for passing data between the **same** version (remoting, `AppDomain`s, etc).

For work between versions, I recommend contract-based serialization; things like `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` (.NET 3.0), or for binary - [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) or similar tools. All of these are *much* better at version tolerance (indeed, you don't even need to deserialize it into the same `Type`); plus they can be used between platforms - so you can serialize in .NET and deserialize in java/C++/etc.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but I found that I have switched to using the DataContractSerializer exclusively since you sugeested it in this post. So thanks after all ;-)

Comment: Would you ever use [OptionalField] for value types such as Booleans or Integers? Or is this attribute only relevant for reference types like in the OP's question?