# Have OptionalField been obsoleted in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

It seems that the [OptionalFieldAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.optionalfieldattribute.aspx) is not longer (if ever) needed for serialization with BinaryFormatter.

With a [example from codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c10071) there is no longer any exception thrown when building the code in Visual Studio 2010, even when targeting older versions of the .NET framework.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929985/whats-up-with-the-optionalfield-attribute) on stackoverflow suggests that it's always been optional. Is this true? And if so, is there actually not any way to get a exception for a missing field, when serializing to binary content in .NET?

Comment: as per the other question, if marc gravell thinks the intent changed shortly before release, it probably did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the exception, add this statement to the deserialization code:

```
        formatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;
```